# How can I access a static action property from JSP? class

Tags: jsp, struts2

I'm working with Struts2 Framework. I don't know why I can't get the value of a static attribute of an Action class in a JSP page. In my code the static attribute I mean is : `nbreAppelAction`. As a result, I get `aa` in all the calls of `stayIndexAction` action which is mapped to `execute()` method. I can't get either 0 in the first time I open my `index.jsp`.

Here it is the Action class :

```
public class UserAction extends ActionSupport{   
    private static int nbreAppelAction = 0;

        public String execute(){
            utilisateur = new User();   
            nbreAppelAction++;
            return SUCCESS;
        }

    public static int getNbreAppelAction() {
        return nbreAppelAction;
    }

    public static void setNbreAppelAction(int nbreAppelAction) {
        UserAction.nbreAppelAction = nbreAppelAction;
    }       
}
```

An here it is index.jsp :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %> 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <body>
        <p>
            <a href="<s:url action='stayIndexAction' />" >Stay in index.jsp </a>
        </p>

        <p>a<s:property value="nbreAppelAction" />a</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Too much whitespace; trim when it's not relevant to the question.

Comment: You can expose the static variable via instance getter/setter in the action just to see if it solves the issue

Answer (score 2):

You need to use static property OGNL notation, and allow access to static properties:

```
@some.package.ClassName@FOO_PROPERTY
@some.package.ClassName@someMethod()
```

http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/ognl-basics.html

I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish here, either. IMO if you want to keep app-wide data, keep it in the application context where it belongs, and synchronize access.

Comment: I added this line in struts.xml : <constant name="struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="true" /> and this one in the page .jsp : <p>a<s:property value="@vs@nbreAppelAction" />a</p> and also i tried this one instead : <p>a<s:property value="@helloworld.action.UserAction@nbreAppelAction" />a</p>, but i still get "aa" as a result and not "a0a" ..

Comment: @user1459961 It's not a public property, not sure what you expect-you'd need to call the accessor. Which is unnecessarily static.

Comment: I can access other attributes of the Action Class from the JSP page without using any getter or setter, although they are declared private.